# Display Hierarchical Data with UltraWinGrid with some customized grid Appearance settings?

Tags: c#, winforms, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I have objects which looks like this:

```
public class ComponentProperty
{        
    public string Property { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
    public string DataType { get; set; }
    public string PropertyKey { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    public string DependencyType { get; set; }
    public object ListType { get; set; }

    public List<ComponentProperty> Properties { get; set; }
}
```

I have information build over in the following form of BindingList where Output is:

```
public class ComponentPropertyList: BindingList<ComponentProperty>
{

}
```

**Scenario:**

List of Component Properties bind to a <kbd>Infragistics Ultra WinGrid</kbd> to generate  Master- Detail View and i made following customization in Grid settings:

```
void ultraGrid1_InitializeLayout(object sender, Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.InitializeLayoutEventArgs e)
{
    ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Override.AllowColSizing = AllowColSizing.Synchronized;
    e.Layout.Bands[0].Override.HeaderAppearance.FontData.Bold = Infragistics.Win.DefaultableBoolean.True;
    ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Appearance.BackColor = Color.White;
    ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Appearance.BackColor2 = Color.White;
    ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Override.ActiveRowAppearance = null;
    ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.BorderStyle = UIElementBorderStyle.None;
    ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Override.BorderStyleCell = UIElementBorderStyle.None;
    ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Override.BorderStyleRow = UIElementBorderStyle.None;
    ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Override.ColumnAutoSizeMode = ColumnAutoSizeMode.Default;
    ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].ColHeadersVisible = true;
    ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Override.RowSelectors = DefaultableBoolean.False;
    ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[0].CellActivation = Activation.NoEdit;
    ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[1].CellActivation = Activation.AllowEdit;
    //Infosys: Nikita - Added for #1143 - START
    ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns["Unit"].CellActivation = Activation.NoEdit;
    //Infosys: Nikita - Added for #1143 - END
    ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[1].CellAppearance.BorderColor = Color.Black;
    ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Override.RowAppearance.TextVAlign = VAlign.Middle;
    // e.Layout.Bands[0].Columns[1].Width = 90;
    ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Scrollbars = Scrollbars.Automatic;
    ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.ScrollBounds = ScrollBounds.ScrollToFill;
    ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.AutoFitStyle = AutoFitStyle.ResizeAllColumns;
    ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[2].AutoSizeMode = ColumnAutoSizeMode.None;
    ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[3].AutoSizeMode = ColumnAutoSizeMode.None;
    ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[2].Hidden = true;
    ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[3].Hidden = true;
    //ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[Constants.Collevel].Hidden = true;
    //ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[Constants.ColID].Hidden = true;
    //ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[Constants.Colparentid].Hidden = true;
    ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns["DependencyType"].Hidden = true;
    ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns["ListType"].Hidden = true;
    //ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Override.AllowColSizing = AllowColSizing.Synchronized;
    ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.BorderStyle = UIElementBorderStyle.Default;


    //ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[1].TabStop = false;
    ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[1].CellAppearance.BackColor = Color.White;

    ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns["Value"].Style = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ColumnStyle.DropDownList;
    ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns["Value"].ButtonDisplayStyle = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ButtonDisplayStyle.Always;

    ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns["Value"].CellAppearance.BackColor = Color.White;

    ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Override.SupportDataErrorInfo = SupportDataErrorInfo.CellsOnly;
    ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[1].SupportDataErrorInfo = DefaultableBoolean.True;

    ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[0].Width = 200;
    ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns["Value"].Width = 120;
    ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns["Value"].TabIndex = 0;
    ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns["Unit"].Width = 60;

    for (int rowCount = 0; rowCount < ultraGrid1.Rows.Count; rowCount++)
    {
        UltraGridRow row = ultraGrid1.Rows[rowCount];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(row.Cells[1].Value)))
        {
            row.Cells[1].Appearance.BackColor = Color.White;
        }
    }

    ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.BorderStyle = Infragistics.Win.UIElementBorderStyle.Solid;
    ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Override.BorderStyleCell = Infragistics.Win.UIElementBorderStyle.Solid;


    ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Override.GroupByRowSpacingAfter = 0;
    ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Override.GroupByRowSpacingBefore = 0;
    ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Override.HeaderPlacement = HeaderPlacement.OncePerGroupedRowIsland;

    if (ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands.Count > 1)
    {
        ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[1].ColHeadersVisible = false;
        ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[1].Columns[2].AutoSizeMode = ColumnAutoSizeMode.None;
        ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[1].Columns[3].AutoSizeMode = ColumnAutoSizeMode.None;
        ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[1].Columns[0].CellActivation = Activation.NoEdit;
        ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[1].Columns[4].CellActivation = Activation.NoEdit;
        ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[1].Columns[2].Hidden = true;
        ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[1].Columns[3].Hidden = true;
        ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[1].Columns["DependencyType"].Hidden = true;
        ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[1].Columns["ListType"].Hidden = true;
        ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[1].Columns[0].Width = 120;
        //ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[1].Columns[0].TabStop = false;
        ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[1].Columns["Value"].Width = 180;
        ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[1].Columns["Value"].TabIndex = 0;
        ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[1].Columns["Unit"].Width = 60;
        //ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[1].Columns[Constants.ColUnit].TabStop = false;
        ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Override.RowSelectors = DefaultableBoolean.False;
        if (e.Layout.Bands[1].Columns.Exists(" ") == true)
        {
            ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[1].Columns[" "].Width = 0;
        }
        if (e.Layout.Bands[1].Columns.Exists(" ") == false)
        {
            ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[1].Columns.Add(" ");
            ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[1].Columns[" "].Header.VisiblePosition = 0;
            ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[1].Columns[" "].Width = 0;
        }
        if (ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands.Count > 2)
        {

            ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[2].ColHeadersVisible = false;
            ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[2].Columns[2].AutoSizeMode = ColumnAutoSizeMode.None;
            ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[2].Columns[3].AutoSizeMode = ColumnAutoSizeMode.None;
            ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[2].Columns[0].CellActivation = Activation.NoEdit;
            ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[2].Columns[4].CellActivation = Activation.NoEdit;
            //ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[2].Override.AllowColSizing = AllowColSizing.None;
            ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[2].Columns[2].Hidden = true;
            ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[2].Columns[3].Hidden = true;

            ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[2].Columns["DependencyType"].Hidden = true;
            ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[2].Columns["ListType"].Hidden = true;
            ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[2].Columns[0].Width = 200;
            ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[2].Columns["Value"].Width = 120;
            ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[2].Columns["Unit"].Width = 60;
            ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Override.RowSelectors = DefaultableBoolean.False;
            //ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[2].Columns[0].TabStop = false;
            ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[2].Columns["Value"].TabIndex = 0;
            //ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[2].Columns[Constants.ColUnit].TabStop = false;
            ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[2].Columns["Value"].Style = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ColumnStyle.DropDownList;
            ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[2].Columns["Value"].ButtonDisplayStyle = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ButtonDisplayStyle.
            if (e.Layout.Bands[2].Columns.Exists(" ") == true)
            {
                ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[2].Columns[" "].Width = 0;
            }
            if (e.Layout.Bands[2].Columns.Exists(" ") == false)
            {
                ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[2].Columns.Add(" ");
                ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[2].Columns[" "].Header.VisiblePosition = 0;
                ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[2].Columns[" "].Width = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    e.Layout.Bands[0].Override.CellAppearance.BorderAlpha = Alpha.Transparent;
    e.Layout.Bands[0].Override.SelectedCellAppearance.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    e.Layout.Bands[0].Override.RowAppearance.BorderAlpha = Alpha.Transparent;
    e.Layout.Bands[0].Override.CellAppearance.BackColorAlpha = Alpha.Transparent;
    e.Layout.Bands[0].Columns[0].CellActivation = Activation.NoEdit;
    e.Layout.Bands[0].Columns[1].CellActivation = Activation.NoEdit;
    e.Layout.Bands[0].Columns[2].CellActivation = Activation.NoEdit;
    ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.AutoFitStyle = AutoFitStyle.ResizeAllColumns;
    ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Override.RowSelectors = DefaultableBoolean.False;
    ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Appearance.BackColor = Color.White;
    //ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Override.AllowColSizing = AllowColSizing.None;
    //ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Override.AllowRowLayoutColMoving = GridBagLayoutAllowMoving.None;
    ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.BorderStyle = UIElementBorderStyle.Solid;
    ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[1].ButtonDisplayStyle = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ButtonDisplayStyle.Always;
    ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.TabNavigation = TabNavigation.NextCell;


    if (e.Layout.Bands[0].Columns.Exists(" ") == true)
    {
        ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[" "].Width = 0;
        //ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[" "].ColSpan = 3;
    }
    if (e.Layout.Bands[0].Columns.Exists(" ") == false)
    {
        ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns.Add(" ").DataType = typeof(bool);
        ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[" "].Header.VisiblePosition = 0;
        ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[" "].Width = 0;
        // ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[" "].ColSpan = 3;
        ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[" "].Style = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ColumnStyle.CheckBox;
        UltraGridColumn checkBox = ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[" "];
    }

    foreach (UltraGridBand band in ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands)
    {
        band.HeaderVisible = false;
    }
}
```

componentProperties collection may have N Level depending on values.

CompoentProperty 1
-------->  SubProperty1
---------------->SubSubProperty1
---------------->SubSubProperty1
CompoentProperty 2
-------->  SubProperty2
---------------->SubSubProperty2
---------------->SubSubProperty2
---------------------->SubSubProperty3
---------------------->SubSubProperty3
---------------------------><kbd>SubSubProperty NN</kbd>

**Problem:**

*Layout is not correct, there are lots of Banding after assigning `DataSource` to grid as `ComponentProperties` Class and Specified `Column Size` does not take any effect on it.
Previously, i was using datatable as datasource that need to replace with object data source. Is there any settings require to work with object datasources.*

[image: Lost of band showing rather than just 3 bands if i have 3 level hierarchy]

Comment: It's not clear what you're after. Do you want the ComponentProperty as the first band (the 'master') and the flattened heirarchy as the 2nd band, or do you want to keep the levels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the some solution from Infragistics fourm, that some what solve the layout problem. As i inspected when i use `IList` then these settings work correct after setting the [MaxBandDepth Property](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2011.2/CLR2.0/html/Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v11.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridLayout~MaxBandDepth.html) at the form load event.

```
// Load only upto two descendant bands. So even if the data source has more than 3 level 
// deep hierarchy, the UltraGrid will only make use of first two levels and ignore the 
// levels deeper than that.
    this.ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.MaxBandDepth = 3;
```

The problem that was occured was similar as asked in below thread:
[First Column of Wingrid Extending too large when datasource is IList](http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/52615.aspx)

> By default, the grid synchronizes the column widths of every band. So
>   in a case like this where ***you have a recursive data source, there
>   are essentially an infinite number of bands and for each band the grid
>   indents a little bit. This means that the first column gets very big
>   in order to accommodate the indentation all the way down the
>   hierarchy.*** The grid limits you to 100 bands of depth by default,
>   but that still means 100 level of indentation.
>
> So there are a number of ways you can handle this.
>
> Set MaxBandDepth on the grid to a smaller value. I recommend a value
>   of between 5 and 8. This will give you pretty good performance on a
>   decent machine and most users probably won't drill down more than 5
>   levels, anyway.  You could set AllowColSizing to Free. This will stop
>   the grid from synchronizing the column widths and allow each band's
>   columns to be sized independently.

References:
[MaxBandDepth Changing After Datasource Set](http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/79157/399683.aspx)
[MaxBandDepth is not being used when the datasource is set](http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/52487.aspx)
[Ultragrid Hierarchical DataSource with Multiple Level Paths](http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/68716/348147.aspx)
[UltraGrid hierarchy](http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/11325/71038.aspx)